# How many chapters does the Toradora! manga have so far?

Tags: toradora

As stated in the title, I'd like to know how many chapters the manga of Toradora! has so far, up to now.

If possible (but unnecessary) I also wouldn't mind knowing what website(s) I could go to for updates on ongoing manga; not the manga itself, but meaning that the website informs about updates to ongoing manga that have new chapters/volumes released.

Comment: [Baka-Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/releases.html) tracks manga scanlation releases for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this list: ***[List of Toradora!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Toradora!_chapters)*** there are 81 chapters. If you would like better descriptions of each chapter you can try the wikia on this page: ***[Chapters - Toradora!](http://tora-dora.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Chapters)*** and select the chapter you would like to learn more about.